# When can GHC infer constraint variables?

Tags: haskell, ghc, constraint-kinds

I am getting type inference errors because GHC will not infer a constraint variable.  It looks inferable by first-order unification.  In further investigation, I found that inserting let-bindings changes the behavior of type inference.  I'd like to know what GHC is doing.

The code here demonstrates the problem.  The newtype `ConstrainedF c` stands for a polymorphic function whose type parameter is constrained by `c`.  As far as I can tell, GHC won't infer `c` based on the values given to `ConstrainedF`.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables, ConstraintKinds, MonoLocalBinds #-}

import Data.Monoid
import GHC.Prim(Constraint)

newtype ConstrainedF c =
  ConstrainedF { runConstrainedF :: forall a. c a => [a] -> a}

applyConstrainedF :: forall c a. c a => ConstrainedF c -> [a] -> a
applyConstrainedF f xs = runConstrainedF f xs

-- GHC cannot infer the type parameter of ConstrainedF
foo :: [Int]
foo = applyConstrainedF (ConstrainedF mconcat) [[1], [2]]
--foo = applyConstrainedF (ConstrainedF mconcat :: ConstrainedF Monoid) [[1], [2]]
```

It should be possible to infer types in the application `ConstrainedF mconcat`:

1. `ConstrainedF` has type `forall c. (forall a. c a => [a] -> a) -> ConstrainedF c`.
2. `mconcat` has type `forall b. Monoid b => [b] -> b`.
3. `forall b. Monoid b => [b] -> b` unifies with `forall a. c a => [a] -> a` by the assignment `a := b` and `c := Monoid`.

However, GHC complains:

```
Could not deduce (Monoid a) arising from a use of `mconcat'
from the context (c0 a).
```

What rules do I have to follow regarding constraint variables so that GHC can infer types?

---

A typical solution for ambiguous type errors is to add proxy values to constrain the ambiguous type.  This was finicky when I tried it.  If I just add an extra parameter to constrain the type of `c`, it works:

```
data Cst1 (c :: * -> Constraint) = Cst1

monoid :: Cst1 Monoid
monoid = Cst1

applyConstrainedF :: forall c a. c a => ConstrainedF c -> Cst1 c -> [a] -> a
applyConstrainedF f _ xs = runConstrainedF f xs

foo :: [Int]
foo = applyConstrainedF (ConstrainedF mconcat) monoid [[1], [2]]
```

But introducing a let binding in `foo` confuses type inference, and it can no longer unify `c` with `Monoid`.

```
foo_doesn't_work :: [Int]
foo_doesn't_work = let cf = ConstrainedF mconcat
                   in applyConstrainedF cf monoid [[1], [2]]
```

Since type inference gets the right answer in one of these two functions, this tells me that GHC will unify constraint variables in some situations but not others.  I don't understand what's going on.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is subtyping. In your example, `c` could as well be `(Monoid b, Eq b)`.

Furthermore, you could then use `Data.Typeable` to inspect what `c` was instantiated with.

Or, what if you asked to "unify" `(c, d)` (a pair of constraints) with `Monoid`?

---

The answer to the second part of your question is — you guessed it! — let generalization.

I know that you guessed it since you've added a `MonoLocalBinds` pragma. However, it doesn't do what you expect here. You see, it only stops generalization of truly local bindings — ones that depend on function parameters or other local bindings.

E.g. this works:

```
foo_does_work :: () -> [Int]
foo_does_work x =
  let cf = const (ConstrainedF mconcat) x
  in applyConstrainedF cf monoid [[1], [2]]
```

For the details see [Let generalisation: Which bindings are affected?](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/blog/LetGeneralisationInGhc7#Whichbindingsareaffected)

Comment: Subtyping would explain why type inference won't unify constraints, but it doesn't explain the problem with `foo_doesn't_work`.  Since 'monoid' is a data value, it isn't subject to subtyping.

Comment: Ok, I haven't got to the second part of your question yet =)